# JavaFX tableview with colorpicker editor

Tags: java, javafx-2

I have a TableView that uses a ColorPicker to (display/edit) colors in a cell. 
The table display the ColorPicker in the desired field, but edits aren't working.

```
TableColumn<SeriesPreferences, Color> c2 = new TableColumn<SeriesPreferences, Color>("Color");
c2.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<SeriesPreferences, Color>("color"));
c2.setCellFactory(new Callback<TableColumn<SeriesPreferences, Color>,
                                TableCell<SeriesPreferences, Color>>()
    {
        @Override
        public TableCell<SeriesPreferences, Color> 
        call(final TableColumn<SeriesPreferences, Color> param)
        {
            TableCell<SeriesPreferences, Color> cell = 
                new TableCell<SeriesPreferences, Color>()
                    {
                        @Override
                        public void updateItem(Color c, boolean empty)
                        {
                            if(c != null)
                            {
                                final ColorPicker cp = new ColorPicker();
                                cp.setValue(c);
                                setGraphic(cp);
                                cp.setOnAction(new EventHandler<javafx.event.ActionEvent>()
                                    {
                                        public void 
                                        handle(javafx.event.ActionEvent t)
                                        {
                                            getTableView().edit(getTableRow().getIndex(), param);
                                            commitEdit(cp.getValue());
                                        }
                                    });
                            }
                        }
                    };
            return cell;
        }
    });

c2.setOnEditCommit(new EventHandler<CellEditEvent<SeriesPreferences, Color>>()
    {
        @Override
        public void handle(CellEditEvent<SeriesPreferences, Color> t)
        {
            ((SeriesPreferences) t.getTableView().getItems().get(t.getTablePosition().
                                                    getRow())).setColor(t.getNewValue());
        }
    });
```

The edit event handler isn't being called when i change the color in the color picker, any ideas?

Comment: did you manage to resolve your issue?

Comment: No i didn't this was par of a project with use both swing/javafx and this part was finally resolved using Swing as there were other issues preventing us to use JavaFX

Answer (score 2):

There's no need to access the JavaFX POJO (or JavaFX Bean) directly if its properties are correctly bound to the table and also it isn't necessary to call anything other than commitEdit.

The answer from Max Beikirch is misleading, because it causes the color picker (and with it the color) to disappear when the table is not in edit mode. It's a workaround to put the table into edit mode, but a bad one. So do this before showing the color picker popup when click on the button:

Write your cell with a color picker like this:

```
public class ColorTableCell<T> extends TableCell<T, Color> {    
    private final ColorPicker colorPicker;

    public ColorTableCell(TableColumn<T, Color> column) {
        this.colorPicker = new ColorPicker();
        this.colorPicker.editableProperty().bind(column.editableProperty());
        this.colorPicker.disableProperty().bind(column.editableProperty().not());
        this.colorPicker.setOnShowing(event -> {
            final TableView<T> tableView = getTableView();
            tableView.getSelectionModel().select(getTableRow().getIndex());
            tableView.edit(tableView.getSelectionModel().getSelectedIndex(), column);       
        });
        this.colorPicker.valueProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
            if(isEditing()) {
                commitEdit(newValue);
            }
        });     
        setContentDisplay(ContentDisplay.GRAPHIC_ONLY);
    }

    @Override
    protected void updateItem(Color item, boolean empty) {
        super.updateItem(item, empty);  

        setText(null);  
        if(empty) {     
            setGraphic(null);
        } else {        
            this.colorPicker.setValue(item);
            this.setGraphic(this.colorPicker);
        } 
    }
}
```

If you're on Java 7, replace the lambdas with anonymous inner classes, but it should work as well. Full blog post is [here](http://info.michael-simons.eu/2014/10/27/custom-editor-components-in-javafx-tablecells/).

Answer (score 1):

Well, I investigated that topic a bit as I have had the same problem. I am afraid to say that JavaFX is just unusable.

I took a look at how others implemented their cells and the key was that were all using something that is representable by a string.
Now, it's the way it always is with Java: Do it the Java-way or be left alone in the rain. The docs for JavaFX are extremely bad at the moment, so I had to try until it works.

So: To trigger the `editCommit`-event, you have to call `setContentDisplay(ContentDisplay. TEXT_ONLY)` in `updateItem()`. That works well if want to display your data as string, but fails completely in cases like these, where a colorpicker just does the job.

Alternatively, it might be possible to fire the event manually. But how do you get the table-position? I don't know.

Comment: commitEdit() doesn't trigger that event because the TableView wasn't in edit mode. That edit mode get's started by your code because you have to double click in the cell in question. Than your color picker is displayed… that maybe works, but your color isn't displayed when not editing a cell.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem for CheckBoxTableCell and DatePickerTableCell and ColorPickerTableCells :-(

I deal it like that: on the events of the controls I get back the POJO objects in use by the "**((Inputs)getTableView().getItems().get(getTableRow().getIndex()**" and I update similary like is it done in the OnEditCommit method...

So for me it's look like this (update the color):

```
 ((Inputs) getTableView().getItems().get(
                    getTableRow().getIndex())
                    ).setColor(cp.getValue());
```

Here is example with ColorPickerCell
:

```
public class ColorPickerTableCell<Inputs> extends TableCell<Inputs, Color>{
private ColorPicker cp;

public ColorPickerTableCell(){        
    cp = new ColorPicker(); 
    cp.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
        @Override
        public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
            commitEdit(cp.getValue());
            updateItem(cp.getValue(), isEmpty());
            ((Inputs) getTableView().getItems().get(
                    getTableRow().getIndex())
                    ).setColor(cp.getValue());
        }            
    });                
    setGraphic(cp);
    setContentDisplay(ContentDisplay.GRAPHIC_ONLY);
    setEditable(true);        
}     
@Override
protected void updateItem(Color item, boolean empty) {
    super.updateItem(item, empty);
    cp.setVisible(!empty);
    this.setItem(item);
    cp.setValue(item);
}
}
```

With this simple JavaFX's POJO:

```
    public ObjectProperty<Color> color = new SimpleObjectProperty<Color>();

    this.color = new SimpleObjectProperty(color);

    public ObjectProperty<Color> colorProperty() {
    return color;
 }

public void setColor(Color color2) {
    color.set(color2);
}
```

I do not know if it's a good way to achive that but it worked for me... Note that the JavaFX's POJO is only accessible within an "ActionEvent" request (combobox, datepicker, colorpicker, etc..)

Regards,

Answer (score 0):

It like Michael Simons said in the comment on the OP. You need to be in **edit mode**. When creating your own custom cells you can trigger edit mode manually by calling `startEdit();` from inside the TableCell.

for example using the focusProperty of your control:

```
    cp.focusedProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
        if (newValue) {
            startEdit();
        }
    });
```